# Solving an ODE numerically vs analytically

Tags: differential-equations

Parameters involved are$\epsilon$

```
ϵ := 1/100
d := 1
x20 = -d/2;
x21 = +d/2;
```

Equation is

```
equ = -1-u'[x2]^2 - u[x2] u''[x2]
```

When I evaluate `DSolve` without specifying any initial value

```
DSolve[equ == 0, u[x2], x2] // Last
```

I get

> ```
> {u[x2] -> Sqrt[E^(2 C[1]) - x2^2 - 2 x2 C[2] - C[2]^2]}
> ```

When I evaluate

```
DSolve[{equ == 0, u[x20] == ϵ, u'[x20] == 0.}, u[x2], x2]
```

I get

> ```
> {{u[x2] -> 1/100 Sqrt[-2499 - 10000 x2 - 10000 x2^2]}}
> ```

And, when I evaluate

```
NDSolve[{equ == 0, u[x20] == ϵ, u[x21] == ϵ}, u[x2], {x2, x20, x21}];
```

I get error messages and no solution.

Each result is different. What is going on?

Comment: The 2 DSolve outputs look like they agree, not sure why you say they're different. The NDSolve output is for a boundary value problem, not an initial value problem. Why would you expect that to be the same?

Comment: @CarlWoll If see better, there is a different sign inside the square root in the first two DSolve outputs. And I expect that the NDSolve case have the same behavior as the first analytical function given by DSolve, an "arc".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think the two [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve) solutions disagree? I think they do agree. One can see this by substituting the right constants in the first [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve) output:

```
soln = u[x2] /. Last @ DSolve[equ == 0, u[x2], x2];
sol1 = soln /. {C[2]->1/2, C[1]->-Log[100]}
```

> Sqrt[-(2499/10000) - x2 - x2^2]

```
sol2 = u[x2] /. Quiet @ First @ DSolve[{equ == 0, u[x20] == \[Epsilon], u'[x20] == 0.}, u[x2], x2]
```

> 1/100 Sqrt[-2499 - 10000 x2 - 10000 x2^2]

Check that they agree:

```
sol1 == sol2 //Simplify
```

> True

Also, why would you expect the boundary value numerical ODE solution to agree with the initial value symbolic ODE solution?

Comment: WoIl. I didnt undertand why you fiz the constants to those values to match the solutions, maybe it is trivial, sorry, I cannot see it. Moreover, I think it is my mistake when I answer you question: I expect that by choosing the first derivative in DSolve I get the solution with boundary values in NDSolve. It is like shooting, right? Anyway, the DSolve cases where to try solve and guess some deruvative. Later I tried NDSolve with BVs, that is the way I must solve the equation. But, if you have test the code lines, an error appears.

Comment: @resanrom (1) Why don't you solve the initial conditions for `C[1]` and `C[2]` and see if they come out to be the values above? (2) Picking `u'[x20] == 0.` is not like shooting.  In the shooting method, you have to search for the value that gives a solution that satisfies the boundary conditions. The value `u'[x20] == 0.` is not the correct one. (3) The problem with your `NDSolve` code not working seems an entirely different question than the one you asked. For the BVP, remove the `n` and try `DSolve[{equ == 0, u[x20] == \[Epsilon], u[x21] == \[Epsilon]}, u, {x2, x20, x21}]`.

Comment: Ok, I got the constants by comparing the solutions. But, my point is, arent those constants the same initial conditions as the first DSolve? And, I tried removing the N for the BVP, and got some errors.

Comment: @resanrom I got warnings, not errors, and a correct solution.